# Design-patterns for memcache-client-like connection management?

Tags: design-patterns

I need to manage connections to a number of services, hosted across a number of servers. Each service is available on more than one server for redundancy.

What I'd like to do is build a client, similar to `memcached` or `beanstalkd` clients, that can connect to the services in a round-robin fashion; if a connection goes down it tries the next one until it has gone through the list N times and no servers are responding.

What (design) patterns should I be researching to implement this? The method of connecting to a service is similar to the others, so is there a pattern that can encompass this also?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a design pattern for this, but you may want to look at a connection pool object.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool